# How to go about loading all posts from firebase database in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-listview

I am building a social media app as a way to learn the basics of Flutter. I have made a way to upload a post, and it uploads data into my Firebase Realtime database like this:

```
-Posts
    postid
        imageurl
        uid
        uemail
        uname
    postid
        etc
```

How should I go about loading this data into a ListView and displaying the username and the image for each post? I have only done this with a recyclerview in Android in the past.

Comment: Without seeing what you've already tried, this is really a bit too broad a topic to answer succinctly on Stack Overflow. I recommend starting with the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data), or one of the many tutorials out there.

Comment: I know how to read the data from firebase, I need to know how to put it into a list and load that list into a listview. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else is trying to figure this out, I ended up following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXBJZD0fBa4&t=2049s), and it was very helpful! It uses a StreamBuilder to load data into  a list, and it seems like a much more simple way to accomplish this than some of the other methods I looked into.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the post from the firebase store.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Posts")
.get()
.then((value) {
      for (var doc in value.docs) {
        print("${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}");
      }
}
```

From the above code, you can get posts from firebase database